# Debugger is not working Inside a particular Class in IOS Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, debugging, compilation, settings, xcode7.2

I am Facing a very Strange Problem in Xcode 7.2 , There is a TableViewCell in my project in which debugger skips the BreakPoint ,even when Compiler goes to the breakpoint as it prints the Log at there. 
(print("Print the Log")), it happens only inside this TableViewCell .

OtherWise inside the Project debugger is doing its job.
Some setting may have been changed I don't know which One :(

Any Solution??